# System is not defined when compile with the --outFile

Tags: typescript

The question is simple: why when compiling with typescript with the --outFile flag I get this error?:

```
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

Just I get this error at bundle time, me would like to get help since I was querying some posts and I didn't get this fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with short questions it helps to include some context and example code:) Anyway, it sounds like the file defining `System` is included after it is used.
From the docs [--outFile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

```
The order of concatenation is determined by the list of files passed to the
compiler on the command line along with triple-slash references and imports.
```

Comment: When i compile without the outFile paramater all is fine but with all javascript compiled files rather than just one, however with the outfile parameter i get that error

Comment: Moreless.. the content of that bundled file is that: https://pastebin.com/BUYJ5Rbv